# Headers not sent with ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

In my React.js app I use the jquery `.ajax` method to retrieve info from a backend API. To do this I need to add a authorization token as a header and I added the `headers` option:

```
$.ajax({
  url: this.props.source,
  headers: { 'Accept':'application/json', 'Authorization':'Token 36d417' },
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data) {
    this.setState({data: data});
  }.bind(this),
  error: function(xhr, status, err) {
    console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
  }.bind(this)
});
```

But I receive a `401 Unauthorized` response from the server. When I check the headers they don't seem to be added?

```
Remote Address:189.28.154.73:8080
Request URL:https://todos-api.com/api/v1/todos?callback=jQuery1100005772984796203673_1424179650018&_=1424179650019
Request Method:GET
Status Code:401 Unauthorized
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,nl;q=0.4
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:todos-api.com
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:https://todos-reactjs.io/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Can you confirm the version of jQuery you are using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the beforeSend callback

```
        $.ajax({
              url: this.props.source,
              beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Token 36d417'); 
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json'); 
              },
              dataType: 'jsonp',
              success: function(data) {
                this.setState({data: data});
              }.bind(this),
              error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
              }.bind(this)
            });
```